# Как написать сниффер с фильтрацией по типу пакета?

Tags: c++

Под ОС семейства Windows! Какие библиотеки использовать? И функции? Каким образом осуществить подсчет входящих и исходящих пакетов на машине с заданным IP адресом?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы начал *(и, вероятно, закончил на ней же)* свой поиск с библиотеки [**libpcap.**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/)
*Для `windows` порт называется [**winpcap.**](http://www.winpcap.org/)*

Для создания снифферов и вообще `packet capture and analysis` вцелом - отличный вариант.

*У этой библиотеки также существует враппер `C++`, который может оказаться более удобным для использования* - [**libcappp.**](http://libpcappp.sourceforge.net/)